# Implementation of `continue` keyword inside iterator pattern

Tags: php, iterator, continue

I found that `continue` functionality can be implemented in iterator pattern only by recursion.
The problem is of course that looping through millions of invalid elements that shall be continued should be ultra slow or ever stack overflow.

How to implement `continue` keyword without using recursion inside iterator pattern?

PHP code with recursion:

```
class TableIterator implements \Iterator
{
    private $row;
    private $fileLines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fileLines = [
            "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8",
            "my condition, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15",
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31",
            "32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, my condition 2, 38",
            "39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46"
        ];
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        reset($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function current(): array
    {
        return $this->row;
    }

    public function key(): int
    {
        return key($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function next(): void
    {
        next($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function valid(): bool
    {
        $this->row = explode(", ", current($this->fileLines));

        if($this->row[0] === 'my condition')
            $this->continue(); // here is the recursion problem
        
        if($this->row[6] === 'my condition 2')
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    
    private function continue()
    {
        $this->next();
        $this->valid();
    }
}

foreach(new TableIterator() as $key => $value)
    print_r($value);
```

I would be glad if there is a solution or hack for PHP.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is the solution!**

I will not bother myself in 2021 to explain it.
Crawl whole algorithm if you are curious.

```
class TableIterator implements \Iterator
{
    private $row;
    private $fileLines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fileLines = [
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8",
            "my condition, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15",
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31",
            "32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, my condition 2, 38",
            "39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46"
        ];
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        reset($this->fileLines);
        
        while($this->continue())
        {
            next($this->fileLines);
        }
    }

    public function current(): array
    {
        return $this->row;
    }

    public function key(): int
    {
        return key($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function next(): void
    {
        do {
            next($this->fileLines);
        }
        while($this->continue());
    }

    public function valid(): bool
    {
        if($this->row[6] === 'my condition 2')
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    
    private function continue()
    {
        $this->row = explode(", ", current($this->fileLines));
        
        return $this->row[0] === 'my condition' ? true : false;
    }
}

foreach(new TableIterator() as $key => $value)
{
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some workaround but it's still **not a desired solution!**

The question might be if there is even any solution at all?

`if($value === null) continue;` continues iteration.
Comment it to get nulls and still be able to get keys. The problem might be when nulls are expected values!

```
class TableIterator implements \Iterator
{
    private $row;
    private $fileLines;
    private $continue;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fileLines = [
            "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8",
            "my condition, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15",
            "my condition, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23",
            "24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31",
            "32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, my condition 2, 38",
            "39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46"
        ];
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        reset($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function current(): ?array
    {
        if($this->continue)
        {
            $this->continue = false;
            return null;
        }
        
        return $this->row;
    }

    public function key(): int
    {
        return key($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function next(): void
    {
        next($this->fileLines);
    }

    public function valid(): bool
    {
        $this->row = explode(", ", current($this->fileLines));

        if($this->row[0] === 'my condition')
            $this->continue = true;
        
        if($this->row[6] === 'my condition 2')
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}

foreach(new TableIterator() as $key => $value)
{
    if($value === null) continue;
    var_dump($value);
}
```